# How to set up locks to prevent stale data being written

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction

I'm mainly a C#/Javascript developer, with only a basic understanding of SQL and databases. I've been doing some reading on transactions and locks, but I'm still struggling to figure out how to set things up to achieve my goals here. I'll get straight into the problem description since that'll illustrate better what I need help with.

I have an application that maintains a somewhat large JSON blob with a bunch of application related data. To simplify, I'll trim down that table to just the essentials here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application]
(
    [ApplicationId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Json] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

We are adding auditing of data changes and we are planning to track them in a separate table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationDataAuditLog]
(
    [ApplicationDataAuditLogId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [ApplicationId] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Applciation]([ApplicationId]),
    [Action] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- Tracks what type of change was made, Add/Modify/Delete
    [DataPath] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, -- The JSON path of the property that was changed
    [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL -- The time of the change, used to ensure we only keep the newest change if data saves get processed out of order
)
```

The catch here is that when we insert a record into the audit log table, we also want to push that change to the JSON blob stored in the Application table. I'll leave out some of the nitty gritty details on the stored proc we wrote to do that, but in essence here's what we wrote to accomplish this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    @applicationId INT,
    @action NVARCHAR(50),
    @dataPath NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @value NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @timestamp DATETIME2
AS
BEGIN

-- Check to make sure there isn't a newer change already saved
DECLARE @isStaleChange BIT = 0
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ApplicationDataAuditLog WHERE ApplicationId = @applicationId AND DataPath = @dataPath AND Timestamp >= @timestamp)
    SET @isStaleChange = 1

IF @isStaleChange = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT TOP 1 @currentJson = a.[Json] FROM Application a WHERE a.ApplicationId = @applicationId

    -- Make the update to the JSON blob (most of the real logic here is excluded for simplicity in this post)
    SET @currentJson = JSON_MODIFY(@currentJson, @dataPath, @value)

    UPDATE Application SET [Json] = @currentJson WHERE ApplicationId = @applicationId
END

-- Leaving out the full insert statement, but you can fill in the blanks here
INSERT INTO ApplicationDataAuditLog ....

END
```

This is all run through an ASP.NET Core API, so we're expecting to have tons of concurrent processes writing this data for multiple different "Applications". What I could use help with is figuring out what I need to add here to ensure that we never lose any data in this process and never write out of date information. So after we make the query at the top to check for "stale" changes, we can't allow any other process to write new changes for this property until we're done making our updates. And then once we pull the JSON blob from the Application table, we can't allow any other process to update that JSON blob for that application until we finish our updates.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to achieve that here?

**Edit #1**

There's not much to clarify in regards to what the JSON looks like - it could look like anything that is valid JSON. But to clarify what the workflow looks like a bit, a request would come in that says "Add property with a path of 'TestProperty' and a value of 12". That'd get applied and you'd end up with something like this in the `Json` column (... represents the data that was already in the object). And then you'd store the details about that change in the audit table.

```
{
  ...
  "TestProperty": 12
}
```

As far as stale data goes, it encompasses a couple different things.

1. Say you have two different requests, one to add a property called
   "Property1", the second to add a property called "Property2". For simplicity, say that the existing state of `Json` is an empty object at that point. The situation I want to avoid is one where both processes read the empty object from `Json`, add their property, and then write it back resulting in an incomplete final object. The first and second objects below are the two possible incomplete objects, whereas the third is the desired result

```
{ "Property1": "a value" }
{ "Property2": "a second value" }
{ "Property1": "a value", "Property2": "a second value" }
```

The other 'stale' situation is if you get multiple concurrent requests to change the same property. The idea was to use the timestamp to make sure we're only applying the change if it's the 'newest' one.

Comment: I mean what criteria do you use to determine it's stale data? You said you want to insert into `dbo.Application` when `dbo.ApplicationDataAuditLog` is inserted into, so what difference does it make *when* that happens? Kinda need more details on what that data looks like that you're storing in the `Json` column and what an example of stale data looks like in a concurrent request.

Comment: @J.D. I added an edit to hopefully help clarify what you were asking about. I will also mention that we're only intending to run updates on the `Application` table and not inserts

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally- volume of writes .. maybe you should find a queuing service to serialise those & stream them in, rather than having multiple writers?
And having queued your write, queue a request to respond once your write is committed, rather than assuming it just worked..

If you need to serialise at the SQL level, then note your audit log will fill very quickly, so it's a poor place to check for the staleness of the json, which is also written to the application table.

Better to add the version stamp to the table with the data and treat the audit as secondary.

That way, you can avoid stale updates by doing things like:

- When reading the application row, take a write lock using a hint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16
  eg,

  `select 1 from Application WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ApplicationId = @applicationId AND [timestamp]=@timestamp`
- just include the timestamp in the where clause of the update & decide if it worked afterwards:

  `UPDATE Application SET [Json] = @currentJson WHERE ApplicationId = @applicationId and [timestamp]=@timestamp if (@@rowcount=0) begin /** errored **/ end`

timestamp is not great for versioning, consider generated guids instead.
Otherwise you need the time granularity of updates to be larger than the granularity of the timestamp you're using.
(a guid version let you easily link to your audit table if you write it there too).

As you'll have multiple updates you'll also want to wrap those in a transaction & check the isolation level that is configured on the server.